# Setup HttpClient in .Net Class library for Integration Test cases

Tags: c#, integration-testing, httpclient, class-library, .net-4.6

I have a class library in .Net 4.6 and associated Test class library. The class library makes the call to a 3rd party Rest API using HttpClient, here is the code

```
public class DemoRepository : HttpBaseRepository, IDemoRepository
{
    internal DemoSection _config;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public DemoRepository (DemoSection config, HttpClient httpClient) : base(httpClient)
    {
        _config = config;
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public Customer GetCustomer()
    {
        string url = _config.Url;//this is coming from app.settings, taken dummy here
        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri(url),
            Headers = {
                { HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString(), "application/json" },
                { "x-appid", _config.AppId }
            },
        };

        var response = _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            throw new Exception(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }

        Customer customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(response.ToString);
        return customer;
    }
```

Here is my Integration test case

```
[TestFixture]
[Category("Integration")]
public class TestDemoRepositoryIntegration
{
    private HttpServer _server;
    private DemoRepository _repo;
    private DemoSection _config;
    private HttpClient _client;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _config = new DemoSection(){ ServiceUrl = "https://test.com/webservices/demo/", AppId = "9YTY8227-demo" };

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        _server = new HttpServer(config);
        _client = new HttpClient(_server);
    }

    public void GetCustomer(string customerNumber)
    {
        _repo = new DemoRepository(_config, _client);
        var res = _repo.GetCustomer();

        Assert.IsNotNull(res);
    }
```

But

```
     var response = _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
```

always return "NotFound" with the error message

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   https://test.com/webservices/demo

but when I hit this method from another project then it works fine and returns the correct result.
I know in .Net core we can make use of TestServer in test cases and that works absolutely fine but I cannot update this project to .Net core.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Professional. The class library is .Net Framework 4.6.

Maybe I am doing something wrong with HttpCLient setup in the Integration test case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The test server (like the whole ASP.NET Core) despite its name is a .NET Standard library, not .NET Core. So it can still be used in .NET Framework. Though you should use at least .NET Framework 4.6.1, better 4.7.

Comment: Other than that you could just do what the above mentioned Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost does, and just replace the default message handler of HttpClient with a test handler which processes your requests.

Comment: No, I can't go with 4.6.1 or later